# What happens to your bounty if no Answers are present on your question?

Tags: support, bounty

I've put a bounty on my question and there is no activity in terms of answers, what will happen to my bounty at the end of the period?

If it does not go back to me would I be able to request attention for my question, I wouldn't want my bounty being wasted. Here's the link if anyone can help me it would be much appreciated:

["No suitable display mode found" error for Dawn of War & DoW: Winter Assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172321/problem-2-dow-1-and-dow-winter-assault)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's gone.  What you're paying reputation for isn't an answer, but more attention.  You've gotten your attention, and that's the most that we can really guarantee.

Comment: well... I guess that sucks a bit because I kinda want an answer to this question in the future which option can I use for prompting an answer to my question through bounty?

Comment: You can't.  There's no way for us to guarantee you get an answer that helps you.  That's why the bounty is put in a special category.  It gets it more attention, and hopefully someone is able to answer your question.

Comment: @nathan you can place another, larger bounty, to attract more attention, or you can see if there might be some way to improve or clarify your question to make it more answerable.

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes sense @LessPop_MoreFizz I have given all the details I can its a lead on from another question I had. All the details are running from the other question too